# Shell scripting - Is it possible to execute .sh file in background

Tags: shell, scripting

I have one `.sh` script. After running this particular file. It is showing list of deleted files. I want to execute this file in the background instead of showing on the shell on which I have run this command.

Please advise, is there any way to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to store the output in a file, or just ignore any output?

Comment: yes, i want to store the output. to track in case of any error..

Comment: You want to discard the output, or store it?  'background' has a specific meaning which does not seem to apply at all here.  It sounds like you just want to redirect the output.

Comment: if redirecting the output is solution then how can i achieve it ?

Comment: if redirecting is not possible then i am fine with ignoring any output.

Comment: yes...this is bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run it like this:

```
./script.sh >/home/username/output.txt 2>&1 &
```

The `&` at the end sends the command to the background.

The `>/home/username/output.txt 2>&1` sends standard error and standard output to `output.txt`.

To keep it running after you log out, change it to this:

```
nohup ./script.sh >/home/username/output.txt 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Hi will...after running above cmd.. Output.txt file contais error as - bash: ./abc.sh: Permission denied

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)

Comment: Do not exit the shell/terminal before the end of the `script.sh` execution otherwise a `SIGHUP` will be sent to the background process, which will likely make it stop. To leave it running in the background try to use `nohup`.

Comment: Great addition @Jayjargot; added a note about it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Jayjargot..for your valuable addition..i will prefer your suggestion.